# css: dragging image doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm trying to move an image around when the user clicks the image and starts moving: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lhf3/3/)
It works in Chrome, but has strange behaviour in FF

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <img .... >
</div>
```

And I handle the javascript as follows

JS:

```
var move = false, prevX;
$('img').on('mousedown', function(e) {
   move = true;
   prevX = e.pageX;
})
  .on('mousemove', function(e) {
      if (move === true) {
          var x = parseInt($(this).css('left')) + e.pageX - prevX;
          $(this).css('left', x);
          prevX = e.pageX;
      }
})
  .on('mouseup', function(e) {
      move = false;
});
```

(In my own code I do a little bit more because you are not allowed to move the image outside certain boundaries)

I don't know why, but in Firefox you can select the image and then it doesn't work anymore. Any suggestions how to fix this in FF ?

Comment: You should add a handler for `mouseout`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return false in your `mousedown` handler to prevent default browser behavior:

```
$('img').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    move = true;
    prevX = e.pageX;
    return false;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Lhf3/5/

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
$(document).on("dragstart", function() {
     return false;
});
```

To the top of your Javascript, this intercepts and prevents the default drag behaviour in the browser, whilst allowing you to override it later to suit your needs. The net effect being the default image ghosting you see on drag in Firefox is prevented by default.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lhf3/6/)